# 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. How can I upgrade that 1 package, or at least know which is?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, package-management, synaptic

I have tried many different solutions found around this and other websites, such as

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt list --upgradeable
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

and no information nor update of the package is displayed.  I also tried

```
aptitude update
```

and checked the log and no information about the package is displayed.

Any ideas on how to identify this package?

My guess at this point, is that it might have something to do with the `sources.list` file. Any comments on this?

I have Linux Mint with the latest distribution Ulyana / Focal.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`apt upgrade` will tell you what it would like to do, including package upgrades; and this will include a list of packages it won’t upgrade:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade -o APT::Get::Show-Upgraded=true
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [any packages which could be auto-removed]
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  [any packages which will be installed]
The following packages have been kept back:
  [any packages which are upgradeable but won’t be upgraded]
The following packages will be upgraded:
  [any packages which will be upgraded]
NN upgraded, NN newly installed, NN to remove and NN not upgraded.
Need to get ... of archives.
After this operation, ... of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

(replacing `NN` with the four different values reflecting the packages listed above).

If this still doesn’t show anything for you, perhaps the non-upgraded package is locally installed (but then, `apt` presumably wouldn’t want to upgrade it...). A good tool to investigate this is `apt-show-versions`:

```
sudo apt install apt-show-versions
```

Then run

```
apt-show-versions | grep "No available version in archive"
```

to see packages which aren’t available in the configured repositories, and

```
apt-show-versions | grep upgradeable
```

to see which packages are upgradeable (regardless of whether `apt` *would* upgrade them).

You can usually find out more about *why* the package is not being upgraded by running `apt install` with the package name. If its upgrade would cause another package to be removed, `upgrade` would skip it, but `full-upgrade` would upgrade it.

Yet another possibility is that the upgrade candidate is blocked; on Linux Mint in particular, this can happen with `snapd`, which is [disabled by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/629680/86440) by the `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref` configuration file.

Answer (score 7):

`apt` will usually do this if upgrading a package requires the removal of another package. You can apply upgrades like these with

```
apt dist-upgrade
```

`apt` will ask you whether you want to actually update the packages, so you can also use this for listing the packages in the first place.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message. The output of `apt dist-upgrade` shows only what is displayed on the title of my question. By only typing  `apt`  the help is displayed, so I am not sure what you mean with your last sentence. In either case, I have no information about the package that is not upgraded.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the same error was due to the presence of the file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref` which is installed by `ubuntu-system-adjustments` Linux Mint package to disable the installation of `snapd`.

Commenting out the content of `nosnap.pref` or removing this file solves the issue.

Comment: This helped me to find the non-upgradable packages. In my case nvidia drivers. Thanks